# PHP replacing value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have this array with city codes:

```
$aryCityCodes = array ("LND", "NY");
```

And this other array with user data:

```
$ary = array (
    array("John", "LND","London"),
    array("Mary", "NY","New York"),
    array("Larry", "AMS","Amsterdam")
);
```

I need to end up with an array like $ary but if the city code in $ary is contained in $aryCityCodes the name of the city in $ary has to be followed by "prime city"

So far, this is what I've done:

```
   if($aryCityCodes)
   {
    if (count($ary) > 0)
    {
        foreach($ary as $item) 
        {

            $bAux= false;
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) 
            { 
                foreach ($aryCityCodes as $aCityCode)
                {

                    if ($aCityCode == $value)
                    {
                        $bAux = true; 
                    }
                    if($bAux)
                    {
                            $value = $value.' prime city'; 

                   }
                }

            }
        }
    }
   }
```

But this does not work, it does not change the name of the city

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output? I can't understand from your question

Comment: `as &$item` and as `&$value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what you need:

```
if($aryCityCodes) {
    if (count($ary) > 0) {
        foreach ($ary as $key => $row) {
            if (in_array($row[1], $aryCityCodes)) {
                $ary[$key][2] .= ' prime city';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Demo : https://eval.in/599514

Check output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => LND
            [2] => London prime city
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mary
            [1] => NY
            [2] => New York prime city
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Larry
            [1] => AMS
            [2] => Amsterdam
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for adding demo, babu

Comment: @Miguel Mas, take a closer look at this solition, particulary at the `foreach` loop. To change value of the source array, he using `$ary[$key][2]`, not the `$row` as you do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Create new array, look in the arrCityCodes array for match (where you can also add strict matching) and append the value if a match is found.

```
$newArray =[];
foreach ($ary as $row) {
    if (in_array($row[1], $arrCityCodes)) {
        $newArray[] = [
            $row[0], $row[1], $row[2] . ' prime city'
        ];
     } else {
        $newArray[] = [
            $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]
        ];
     }
}
```

The benefit here is that you still have access to the original object which can be handy sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

foreach is working on a copy of your data, if you dont explicitly specify it should be "by reference".

Change both foreaches like so:

```
    foreach($ary as &$item)
```

And

```
        foreach ($item as $key => &$value)
```